# Name of resource different between getResource and getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, classloader

Can anyone explain this :

```
classLoader.getResource("folder/file.txt")            // works
classLoader.getResource("/folder/file.txt")           // returns null
classLoader.getResourceAsStream("folder/file.txt")    // returns null
classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/folder/file.txt")   // works
```

I couldn't understand it from any documentation I'd just read.

Comment: Were is "folder" exactly?  When I throw folder/file.txt in src/main/resources it finds the file for both calls without the leading slash, and returns null for both with the slash.

Comment: Assuming that `classLoader` is an instance of `java.lang.ClassLoader`, there should be no difference and they should all work or not work. If the object is an instance of `java.lang.Class` then the leading `/` makes the name an _absolute_ name, whereas no leading `/` means the name is relative to the class' package.

Comment: ClassLoader is simply SomeClass.class.getClassLoader()

Comment: The resource is in my maven project under /src/main/resources/folder/file.txt